# Control contour line transparency plot.kde

Tags: r, plot, transparency, contour, kernel-density

I'm using plot.kde in library(ks) to extract contour levels of kernel density plots. I'd like to overlay multiple plots so I'm making the contour fills semi-transparent. However, there is a border/contour line whose color I just can't seem to control.

I have tried changing all of the different col,cont.col,color (etc) options in the plot.kde function and just can't seem to hone in on the color of the contour itself. I could probably use some work around by extracting the coordinates of the contour from the kde object and then plotting this using the polygon() function, but I'd really like to control this from within plot.kde. It's something I'll be running many times.

This is likely super simple but I'm just missing it! In the figure below, it's the thicker red line I'm trying to control.

Thanks!!!

```
library(ks)
data(unicef)
H.scv <- Hscv(x=unicef)
fhat <- kde(x=unicef, H=H.scv, compute.cont=TRUE)
plot(fhat, display="filled.contour2", cont=c(10),col=c(NA,rgb(1,0,0,0.5)))
```

[image]